# Setting a matplotlib sliders label position

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pretty basic question. Is there a way to switch the label position from the default (where the label is to the left) to be on top of the slider? I'm assigning the slider in a loop as so:

```
for i in range(10):
    sld[i] = Slider(axes([0.7, .9-(i-1)*.1, .2, .05]), \
    description[i], minval[i], maxval[i], valinit = val[i])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. It looks like you pass a number to a legend function as `loc=<id>` where `<id>` is a location as defined by the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html).

Comment: `matplotlib.widgetsSlider` has no `loc` argument: `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no property 'loc'`